# What is the best way to preallocate memory for each OpenMP thread to avoid repeated heap allocations inside a loop?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a parallelized for loop that looks like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
    InnerFunction();
}
```

The problem is that InnerFunction needs to utilize and dynamically resize heap memory data containers, such as a vector. Ie, InnerFunction looks something like this:

```
void InnerFunction() {
    vector<double> vec;
    //and then vec is subsequently resized as part of the function operation, which is being omitted here for brevity
}
```

InnerFunction does not know in advance how big the vector needs to become, which is why it can't use std::array.

Based on testing, I believe that the function is experiencing a performance problem (ie, slowdown) because the inner loop is constantly allocating and releasing heap memory.

So instead, I rewrote the function to do this:

```
vector<vector<double>> outervec;
outervec.resize(omp_get_max_threads());

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
    InnerFunction(outervec[omp_get_thread_num()]);
}

void InnerFunction(vector<double> &vec) {
    vec.clear();
    //and then vec is subsequently resized as part of the function operation, which is being omitted here for brevity
}
```

This works because vec.clear() does not release the heap memory. So, in most runs through the function, InnerFunction can utilize previously allocated heap memory without any new allocation or release of memory.

Is my implementation the 'right' way to accomplish my objective? Is there a 'best practice' way to do this, or something built-in to OpenMP? It appears that my implementation works (ie, it's not crashing), but I am unsure if: (a) it's the most efficient (ie, is there meaningful overhead from running omp_get_thread_num many times in an inner loop, and if so, could this be avoided?), (b) is there any lurking thread-safe issue that I am missing, and (c) is there a better coding 'style' implementation that would have to rely on using omp_get_thread_num calls?

Intuitively, it seems like this scenario ought to be fairly common for OpenMP implementations, and I wonder if OpenMP has something built-in to facilitate it.

Comment: The `vec` you pass to each thread is *not* allocated, it will be empty.

Comment: It is subsequently resized as part of the code that I am omitting for brevity, where I wrote "//and then vec is subsequently resized as part of the function operation".

Comment: Then that `clear` call doesn't make sense. Unless the vector will already have some content when the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ runtime library is pretty efficient if you repeatedly alloc a block of the same size. (I've tested it and basically saw no performance difference between "allocating" a block in each iteration, and passing an array from the outside.) I'm not sure if that's still true if the arrays are different size.

Idea: let each iteration create a vector with enough `capacity` for the worst case, but determine the `size` dynamically. This of course presumes that there is a worst case upper bound.

Comment: This inner loop is going to be run many times. I am pretty skeptical that having it allocated/deallocate many times is going to be efficient, regardless of whether the block of memory is 'always the same size'.

Comment: @MarkMc In practice, the implementation does deallocate/reallocate only when needed, i.e. when the new size is greater than the old size and there's not enough contiguous free space in memory beyond the end of the vector.

Comment: @MarkMc true allocation is done by the operating system, but the C++ runtime library keeps its own list of free/used blocks. If you ask for a block immediately after it was freed, it's probably going to be found without having to go through the OS allocation process. I invite you to test this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks quite a valid approach. Note however that you can further simplify the structure by declaring the vector in the parallel region:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    vector<double> vec;
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
        InnerFunction(vec);
    }
}

void InnerFunction(vector<double> &vec) {
    vec.clear();
    //and then vec is subsequently resized as part of the function operation, which is being omitted here for brevity
}
```

But ultimately I would decouple the allocated size from the needed size, and I would resize only when a larger size is needed.

```
void InnerFunction(vector<double> &vec) {
    ...
    if (needed_size > vec.size()) vec.resize(needed_size);
    vec.clear();
    ...
}
```